# Anyone else noticed the tide of low-quality questions since the introduction of the new "be nice" policy?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, statistics, code-of-conduct

As of late, I have certainly noticed an influx of low-quality questions. These questions are typically of the following caliber:

- Help with a homework assignment
- Incoherent and poorly-articulated even when it's obvious English is their native language
- No indication that the asker has debugged their issue ("it doesn't work why")
- Distinct lack of understanding of fundamental basics

I will say that I haven't been using SE as much lately, but the frequency that I encounter low-quality questions is certainly far higher now than it has ever been. Could it be that there are new algorithms that are giving lower-quality answers higher priority in an effort to give beginner questions more exposure? If not, I wonder if the new "be nice" policy can be held to account to a degree. It seems like all this new coddling has ushered in a wave of programmers that lack any sense of resourcefulness or self-sufficiency. I am all for being considerate to newcomers as I was once naive in my field, but I can assert as fact that I always made every attempt to grasp the basics before heading off to a Q&A forum to ask for help.

Anyway, I await the inevitable thrashing that I will take for this post. Please, do not be kind. Hit me with your worst.

Comment: We did just past September... Every year when school starts, we see a bit more low quality, then it stabilizes back to where it was. I think its too early to blame it on anything else than seasonality

Comment: Did you also notice the tide of VLQs starting at each semester beginnings?

Comment: _"Please, do not be kind. Hit me with your worst."_ [Here you go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvWHQMH-G4A) :-D

Comment: 'Please do not be kind?' Common human decency prevents me from granting that request.  Youngsters often need guidance.  Firm criticism should never be cruel or obnoxious unless your aim is to produce a generation of cruel and obnoxious young adults.

Comment: I believe that the amount of bad posts is because of September, too, but I feel like I see more upvotes on low quality posts, sometimes accompanied by a comment asking to be nice and to not downvote new contributors.

Comment: @ModusTollens While I've only seen one such comment saying not to downvote new people, I *have* noticed more upvotes on poor questions lately (although idk what that could be attributed to). It's not uncommon when browsing the new question feed to see 5 or so questions in a row, all upvoted; seemingly regardless of their quality. It's almost like people are trying to counteract perceived negativity.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've seen this, too. Even with answers. I was browsing the list of newest "short answers", and every answer that should obviously have been a comment was upvoted. All in a row.

Comment: @ModusTollens I really hope it isn't intentional mass voting disregarding quality. The solution to "too many downvotes" isn't to make voting less meaningful.

Comment: I thought it actually improved a bit in September, awfully subjective measure.  Hard number-wise it did absolutely nothing to increase the number of questions.  The average number of answers per question actually improved a bit, after years of steady decline, but mostly because of a decreasing number of questions.  And the number of downvotes are down pretty hard (~18%), right after the campaign got started with no trend to reverse.  Doubtful that anybody will consider that a sign of quality improvement :)

Answer (score 3):

I hazard a guess that this isn't really true. Historically speaking, we always have an influx of homework and very beginner type questions around september. This after all is when a new semester starts for most of the world's students. That means a fresh batch of students that are confronted with their very first programming problems. It stands to reason that some % of these new students decide to ask their homework problems on Stack Overflow.

There might be lingering effects from the new code of conduct campaign, such as the decline in downvotes that Hans Passant mentioned in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375293/anyone-else-noticed-the-tide-of-low-quality-questions-since-the-introduction-of#comment637941_375293), but I think the influx of low quality questions can just be explained with the yearly cycle.